# How can I detect bright area

Tags: python

I want to find the (x, y) coordinate of center of the largest bright area in the image.
This is the example image 
http://postimg.org/image/id3k558bx/

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to provide more examples of what you are trying to accomplish here. The question is hard to answer as it stands.

Answer (score -1):

Now that you changed your question and added an example image:

```
import scipy.ndimage as img
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
image = img.imread('threshold_Image.jpg', flatten=True)

image_thresh= image
threshold = 127  # half of the maximum - might want to vary it if your image is noisy etc.
image_thresh[image < threshold] = 0

labeled, num_objects = img.label(image_thresh)
slices = img.find_objects(labeled)
xcomlist, ycomlist = [], []
for peakslice in slices:
    y, x = peakslice
    xcom, ycom= img.measurements.center_of_mass(image[peakslice])
    xcom += x.start
    ycom += y.start
    xcomlist.append(xcom)
    ycomlist.append(ycom)

plt.imshow(image_thresh)
plt.plot(xcomlist, ycomlist, 'gx')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Might I ask on why the downvoting?

Comment: Thank you very much, how to process this image with opencv in python, I don't enough reputation to vote up or down, sorry

Comment: It's pretty much the same. You just have to find the equivalent functions in the opencv module. E.g. the Com is calculated by the moment operation. Have a look at http://answers.opencv.org/question/460/finding-centroid-of-a-mask/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968332/calculate-the-center-of-a-contour-area .